# meaning of "$f_n(z)$ converges uniformly towards $f(z)$ over compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$"

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let

$$f_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^n\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}\tag{1}$$

$$f(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(z)=\cos(z)\tag{2}$$

What does it mean by the following statement?

$f_n(z)$ converges uniformly towards $f(z)$ over compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

In other words, what facts (reasoning) do we need to show first and then to conclude with the statement:
Thus $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly towards $f(z)$ over compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: "For every compact $K\subset\mathbb{C}$, the restrictions $f_n\lvert_K$ converge uniformly to $f\lvert_K$." It suffices to prove the uniform convergence on all disks centered at $0$ with integer radius, for example. That's because every compact subset of the plane is contained in such a disk, and uniform convergence is preserved by restriction.

Comment: @DanielFischer. Thanks a lot for the answer. Let $K$ be a disk of radius $m>0,m\in\mathbb{N}$ centered at 0. Do I need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ (possibly dependent on $m$ as well), such that when $n>N$, $|f_n(z)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ for $|z|\le m$?

Comment: Basically yes. But depending on what you already have proved, there are various short-cuts. For example you might use that a power series always converges uniformly on every compact subset of its domain of convergence if that is a theorem already proven.

Comment: @DanielFischer. Thanks a lot for the guidance. In my case, $f_n(z)$ is a finite sum of some polynomials times some exponential decay functions. The restriction of $f_n(z)$ to $K$ will definitely simplify the proof. Best